# Create Sprite objects using sf::sprite

Tags: c++, sfml

Code:

```
#include <SFML/Graphics.hpp>
#include <iostream>
#include <chrono>
#include <thread>
#include <string>
#include <string.h>

static void threadSleep(int newMilli) {
    std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::milliseconds(newMilli));
}


int main() {
    // Sprite =======

    bool gate = true;

    sf::Texture texture;
    if (!texture.loadFromFile("index.png")) {
        std::cout << "Error loading index.png:" << std::endl;
    } else { std::cout << "Loaded 'index.png'" << std::endl; }

    // sprite0
    sf::Sprite sprite;
    sprite.setTexture(texture);
    sprite.setTextureRect(sf::IntRect(0, 0, 10, 10));
    float x = 315, y = 235;
    sprite.setPosition(x, y);

    // sprite1
    sf::Sprite sprite1;
    sprite1.setTexture(texture);
    sprite1.setTextureRect(sf::IntRect(0, 0, 10, 10));
    float x1 = 305, y1 = 235;
    sprite1.setPosition(x1, y1);

    // sprite2
    sf::Sprite sprite2;
    sprite2.setTexture(texture);
    sprite2.setTextureRect(sf::IntRect(0, 0, 10, 10));
    float x2 = 295, y2 = 235;
    sprite2.setPosition(x2, y2);

    // sprite3
    sf::Sprite sprite3;
    sprite3.setTexture(texture);
    sprite3.setTextureRect(sf::IntRect(0, 0, 10, 10));
    float x3 = 285, y3 = 235;
    sprite3.setPosition(x3, y3);

    // sprite4
    sf::Sprite sprite4;
    sprite4.setTexture(texture);
    sprite4.setTextureRect(sf::IntRect(0, 0, 10, 10));
    float x4 = 275, y4 = 235;
    sprite4.setPosition(x4, y4);

    // Starting Window ==========================
    sf::RenderWindow window(sf::VideoMode(640, 480), "-Pandora's Box-");

    //   Window----------------------------------------------------------------------
    while (window.isOpen()) {
        sf::Event event;

        //==============================
        while (window.pollEvent(event)) {

            // The Message Loop (Brain of Program)
            switch (event.type) {

                // Close Window
            case sf::Event::Closed:
                window.close();
                break;

            case sf::Event::KeyPressed:
                switch (event.key.code) {

                case sf::Keyboard::A:
                    std::cout << "[a] -pressed-\n" << std::endl;

                    x4 = x3; y4 = y3;  // This just makes x4 copy x3 
                    x3 = x2; y3 = y2;  // and x3, x2, x1, x;...
                    x2 = x1; y2 = y1;  
                    x1 = x; y1 = y;

                    sprite.setPosition(x -= 10, y);
                    sprite1.setPosition(x1, y1);
                    sprite2.setPosition(x2, y2);
                    sprite3.setPosition(x3, y3);
                    sprite4.setPosition(x4, y4);

                         break;
                 case sf::Keyboard::W:
                     std::cout << "[w] -pressed-\n" << std::endl;

                     x4 = x3; y4 = y3;
                     x3 = x2; y3 = y2;
                     x2 = x1; y2 = y1;
                     x1 = x; y1 = y;

                     sprite.setPosition(x, y -= 10);
                     sprite1.setPosition(x1, y1);
                     sprite2.setPosition(x2, y2);
                     sprite3.setPosition(x3, y3);
                     sprite4.setPosition(x4, y4);

                     break;
                case sf::Keyboard::D:
                     std::cout << "[d] -pressed-\n" << std::endl;

                     x4 = x3; y4 = y3;
                     x3 = x2; y3 = y2;
                     x2 = x1; y2 = y1;
                     x1 = x; y1 = y;

                     sprite.setPosition(x += 10, y);
                     sprite1.setPosition(x1, y1);
                     sprite2.setPosition(x2, y2);
                     sprite3.setPosition(x3, y3);
                     sprite4.setPosition(x4, y4);

                     break;
                case sf::Keyboard::S:
                     std::cout << "[s] -pressed-\n" << std::endl;

                     x4 = x3; y4 = y3;
                     x3 = x2; y3 = y2;
                     x2 = x1; y2 = y1;
                     x1 = x; y1 = y;

                     sprite.setPosition(x, y += 10);
                     sprite1.setPosition(x1, y1);
                     sprite2.setPosition(x2, y2);
                     sprite3.setPosition(x3, y3);
                     sprite4.setPosition(x4, y4);

                    break;
                case sf::Keyboard::Space:
                    std::cout << "[space] -pressed-\n" << std::endl;

                    break;
                }
                break;

            case sf::Event::Resized:
                std::cout << event.size.width << " : " << event.size.height << std::endl;
                break;
            case sf::Event::LostFocus:
                std::cout << "[Pandora Box] -Lost Focus-\n" << std::endl;
                break;
            case sf::Event::GainedFocus:
                std::cout << "[Pandora Box] -Gained Focus-\n" << std::endl;
                break;

            }

        }


        window.clear();
        //===========================
        if (gate == true) {
            window.draw(sprite);
            window.draw(sprite1);
            window.draw(sprite2);
            window.draw(sprite3);
            window.draw(sprite4);
            } 
        //===========================
        window.display();
    }

    return 0;
}
```

What I'm trying to do is when I press "Space" at "case sf::Event::KeyPressed:" then create a new sprite. like at the beginning the code: "sf::Sprite sprite", but something similar to an array like "sprite[#]". But Idk how, I've looked to see if a "sf::Sprite" can have an array but couldn't really find anything on it.

for example:

```
case sf::Keyboard::Space:
    counter += 1  // counter ='s 6 now
    sf::Sprite sprite[counter];

    sprite[counter].setTexture(texture);
    sprite[counter].setTextureRect(sf::IntRect(0, 0, 10, 10));
    float x = #, y = #; // don't worry about x or y
    sprite[counter].setPosition(x, y);

    break;
```

of course I would change the sprite0-sprite4 to the same format thing (using arrays), but Does anyone know how I can do this? i couldn't find anything like this online, and I doubt anyone on stackoverflow already asked this question (already searched)

if it's easy and simple fix, please comment/reply, I'm pretty new to C++ and SFML

-Thanks in advance.

*This program using SFML, a game-like-graphics Library*

*Also this is like a game of snake, current all it can do it move around with 5 blocks (10x10 pixels) like the original snake game does.*

Comment: So you just want a dynamic, growable array of sprites. So use a `std::vector`. http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector

Answer (score 1):

std::vector is what you are looking for:

```
std::vector<sf::Sprite> sprites;
```

When you press Space:

```
sf::Sprite sprite;
// Initialization here
sprites.push_back(sprite);
```

Then when you use it:

```
sprites[x].setTexture(SomeTexture);
```

Comment: if i could, what does "push_back()" do?

Comment: It inserts a copy of your sprite at the end of your vector.